# How to make sidebar fixed when scroll like sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok. i have a problem with my sidebar. i want make the left sidebar fixed and go up when i scroll down over "Hello, world ?" and the sidebar will go up like STICKY. i dont want use a plugin. i need some short code. it's only use for that. help me with jsfiddle. thank you

```js
*/i want use javascript.../
```

```css
#header { clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: darkorange; border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d3; border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d3; margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;}


h1.head {font-family: verdana; font-size: 200%;}

a { color: orange;}

.sidebar { float: left; width: 25%; height: 100%;}

#text { float: left; width: 70%;}

body { text-align:center;}

p, p a {text-align: left; font-size: 90%;}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
 <h1 class="head"><b>Hello, world ?</b></h1>
</div>

<div id="bar-fixed">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="text">
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
</div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

I guess I know what you want. Updated the code with Javascript.

I am setting a limit scrolling beyond which I will be adding a class called `.stickIt` to the sidebar and fixing it at one place.

**DEMO:**

```js
/* it seems javascript..*/
var topLimit = $('#bar-fixed').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //console.log(topLimit <= $(window).scrollTop())
  if (topLimit <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('#bar-fixed').addClass('stickIt')
  } else {
    $('#bar-fixed').removeClass('stickIt')
  }
})
```

```css
#header {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d3;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
h1.head {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 200%;
}
a {
  color: orange;
}
#bar-fixed {
  width: 30%;
}
#bar-fixed.stickIt {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#text {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
p,
p a {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="head"><b>Hello, world ?</b></h1>
  </div>

  <div id="bar-fixed">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a>
      </p>
      <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a>
      </p>
      <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a>
      </p>
      <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a>
      </p>
      <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="text">
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
    <p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed;` for the ID `bar-fixed` in CSS.

Comment: not like that.. if i use that. it will make the sidebar have space in the top.

Comment: Yes, correct. But you need to use other styles to place the sidebar. If you want, I can show.

Answer (score 1):

Leap forward to 2020 and it's much easier now:

```
#bar-fixed {
    height: 100vh;
    top: 10px; /* or whatever top you need */
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
*/i want use javascript.../
```

```css
#header { clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: darkorange; border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d3; border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d3; margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;}


h1.head {font-family: verdana; font-size: 200%;}

a { color: orange;}

.sidebar { float: left; width: 25%; height: 100%;}

#text { float: right; width: 70%;}

body { text-align:center;}

p, p a {text-align: left; font-size: 90%;}

#bar-fixed { position: fixed; }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
 <h1 class="head"><b>Hello, world ?</b></h1>
</div>

<div id="bar-fixed">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
  <p class="bar"><a href="#">
  Make this fixed when scroll</a></p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="text">
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
<p>I want the sidebar fixed when i scroll down over the Header. and the sidebar will go up LIKE STICKY SIDEBAR</p>
</div>
  
</body>
```